# How to retrieve data from fire-base into a new activity On-click RecyclerView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

It's an app that retrieves book data from firebase, I want to know how to retrieve specific data into a new activity. Like, retrieve specific book data on click RecyclerView. I am able to get the onclick position on the RecyclerView but I don't know how to use that with firebase

**Here is my code:**

```
public class SearchPage extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText searchbar;

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    DatabaseReference reference;

    ArrayList <String> BookNameList;
    ArrayList <String> AuthorNameList;
    ArrayList <String> PicList;
    ArrayList <String> PublisherList;
    ArrayList <String> Shelfnols;
    ArrayList <String> Desc;
    SearchAdapter searchAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_page);

        searchbar = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchbar);
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        reference.keepSynced(true);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL));
        BookNameList = new ArrayList <> ();
        PublisherList = new ArrayList <> ();
        AuthorNameList = new ArrayList <> ();
        Shelfnols = new ArrayList <> ();
        PicList = new ArrayList <> ();
        Desc = new ArrayList <> ();
        final ArrayList <String> uidlist = new ArrayList <String> ();




        searchbar.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!s.toString().isEmpty()) {
                    setAdapter(s.toString());

                } else {
                    BookNameList.clear();
                    AuthorNameList.clear();
                    PicList.clear();
                    PublisherList.clear();
                    Shelfnols.clear();
                    Desc.clear();
                    uidlist.clear();

                }
            }

            private void setAdapter(final String searchedString) {
                reference.child("books").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        BookNameList.clear();
                        AuthorNameList.clear();
                        PicList.clear();
                        PublisherList.clear();
                        Shelfnols.clear();
                        Desc.clear();
                        uidlist.clear();


                        int counter = 0;
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String uid = snapshot.getKey();

                            String desc = snapshot.child("Desc").getValue(String.class);
                            String bookname = snapshot.child("bookname").getValue(String.class);
                            String author = snapshot.child("author").getValue(String.class);
                            String image = snapshot.child("image").getValue(String.class);
                            String publisher = snapshot.child("Publisher").getValue(String.class);
                            String shelfno = snapshot.child("Shelf_no").getValue(String.class);
                            try {


                                if (bookname.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())) {
                                    BookNameList.add(bookname);
                                    AuthorNameList.add(author);
                                    PublisherList.add(publisher);
                                    Shelfnols.add(shelfno);
                                    PicList.add(image);
                                    Desc.add(desc);

                                    counter++;
                                } else if (author.toLowerCase().contains(searchedString.toLowerCase())) {
                                    BookNameList.add(bookname);
                                    AuthorNameList.add(author);
                                    PublisherList.add(publisher);
                                    Shelfnols.add(shelfno);
                                    PicList.add(image);
                                    Desc.add(desc);
                                    counter++;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }


                            if (counter == 15) {
                                break;
                            }
                            SearchAdapter searchAdapter = new SearchAdapter(SearchPage.this, BookNameList, AuthorNameList, PicList, PublisherList, Shelfnols);
                            recyclerView.setAdapter(searchAdapter);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }
```

**This is my adapter class**

```
public class SearchAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder> {
public static final String id="key";
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> BookNameList;
    ArrayList<String> AuthorNameList;
ArrayList<String> PicList;
ArrayList<String> PublisherList;
ArrayList<String> Shelfnols;
LinearLayout booklayout;




class SearchViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ImageView bookimage;
    TextView bookname, authorname,publisher,shelfno;

    public SearchViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        bookimage =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.Bookimg);
        bookname =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.BookName);
        authorname =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.AuthorName);
        publisher =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.Publications);
        shelfno =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.Shelfno);
        booklayout=itemView.findViewById(R.id.LinLayout);
    }
}

public SearchAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> bookNameList, ArrayList<String> authorNameList, ArrayList<String> picList,ArrayList<String> publisherList,ArrayList<String> shelfnols) {
    this.context = context;
    BookNameList = bookNameList;
    AuthorNameList = authorNameList;
    PicList = picList;
    PublisherList=publisherList;
    Shelfnols=shelfnols;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder  onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.activity_search_layout,parent,false);
     return new SearchAdapter.SearchViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SearchViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.bookname.setText(BookNameList.get(position));
    holder.authorname.setText(AuthorNameList.get(position));
    holder.publisher.setText(PublisherList.get(position));
    holder.shelfno.setText(Shelfnols.get(position));
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                String t=String.valueOf(position);
            Toast.makeText(v.getContext(), "Item is clicked" + t, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

   booklayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

       }

   });
```

this the new activity where i want the book details to be shown

```
public class Bookdetailslayout extends SearchPage {

DatabaseReference reference;
TextView bookname,author,publisher,desc,location;
ImageView image;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {



    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bookdetailslayout);

    bookname = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bkname);
    author = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aname);
    publisher = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pname);
    desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bkdescription);
    location = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bklocation);
    String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");


    DatabaseReference databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("books");
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            Bookdeets bookdeets=dataSnapshot.getValue(Bookdeets.class);


            bookname.setText(bookdeets.getBookname());



        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });



}



    Glide.with(context).asBitmap().load(PicList.get(position)).placeholder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round).into(holder.bookimage);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return BookNameList.size();
}
```

Comment: Looks like you get your data on Firebase then passed into Adapter via some `ArrayList<Object>`. You can get your data `onClick` with by using `position`: `BookNameList.get(position)`.. etc

Comment: You need to pass `uid` to your adapter which can be used to retrieve a single value from Firebase

Comment: What's wrong with the shared code?

Comment: Please post database structure and which activity you want to send intent

Comment: @AlexMamo this codes works fine but i have been trying to set onclick listener to the recycler view to go to a new activity where it will display specific book details

Answer (score 0):

```
      holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           Intent i = new Intent(context,BookdetailsActivity.class);
           i.putExtra("bookname",bookname);
           context.startActivity(i);
       }
   });
```

above code start new activity for showing details on new activity at the same time pass unique key for retrieving data from firebase.

**inside BookDetailsActivity**
get key value by using

> String name = getIntent().getStringExtra("bookname");

then do your stuff for getting data from firebase.

Comment: im not able to use bookname its throwing a error ,cannot resolve ..i defined it under onBindviewholder in my adapter class